# Solving this trigonometric equation: $\sqrt{3} \cos x - 3 \sin x = 4 \sin 2x \cos 3x$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sqrt{3} \cos x - 3 \sin x = 4 \sin 2x \;\cos 3x$$

I tried many things: opening $\sin 2x$, $\cos 3x$, simplifying LHS: $\cos(60^\circ+x)$. Nothing seems to work.

Any hint?

Comment: Try using $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$, $\cos 3x = \cos 2x \cos x - \sin 2x \sin x$ and $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^ x$

Comment: I tried it, it's making it more complex..

Comment: Try [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%7B3%7D+cos+x+-+3+sin+x+%3D+4+sin+2x+cos+3x).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) says: $$2\sin2x\cos3x=\sin5x-\sin x$$

So, we have 
$$\sqrt3\cos x-3\sin x=2(\sin5x-\sin x)$$

$$\iff\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x=2\sin5x$$

$$\iff2\sin(60^\circ -x)=2\sin5x$$

Hope you know about the general solution of $\displaystyle\sin x=\sin\alpha$

Comment: So simple and smart !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thanks. Hope I didn't make any silly mistake. Nice question, I must admit

Comment: Thanks Lab bhattacharjee, you're always ready to help! :)